# PBS (pro) - where can I find the STDOUT and STDERR while job is running?

Tags: stdout, pbs

I submitted (`qsub`) a (very) long-running job to the PBS-pro scheduler. I set the paths for STDOUT and STERR using the `-o` and `-e` options, but these will only be written at the end of the run, and I'd like to check the progress of the job while running, indicated in the STDOUT. I know I should have redirected (`>`) the STDOUT, but I didn't.
I am assuming STDOUT and STERR are written somewhere on the local disk of the exec host, but couldn't find out where. Is there some default or some way to determine the path?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer: on my system it can be found under: `/var/spool/pbs/spool/` on the exec host.